# How to add datetime in python

Tags: python, time

My code :

```
from datetime import datetime, date,time
timeobj = time(0, 5)
start = datetime.now().time()
time1 = datetime.combine(date.min, start) - datetime.combine(date.min, timeobj)
tx = start+time1 # throws error in here
if (start >= tx):
   pass #do stuff
```

I'm getting this error :

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.timedelta'

Can someone help me fix this problem? I just want to use the `"if"` statement above.

Comment: What line does the error refer to?

Comment: i think datetime.time and datetime.timedelta cannot be added

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to accomplish here?  It seems overly convoluted.

Comment: @ScottHunter, i simplified this SO without the need to convert between datetime and timedelta

Answer (score 0):

Here's my suggestion:

```
from datetime import datetime, date, time
timeobj = time(0,5)
start = datetime.combine(date.min, datetime.now().time())
time1 = datetime.combine(date.min, start) - datetime.combine(date.min, timeobj)
tx = (start+time1).time()
if start.time() > tx:
    pass # do stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that `start` is a datetime.time object and `time1` is a timedelta between two datetime.datetimes, therefore the `+` operator is not meaningful for combining them hence the error. 
I am not entirely sure what you are trying to achieve, but in general make sure your `start` variable is of a kind that the timedelta can be added to, e.g.:

```
from datetime import datetime, date,time
timeobj = time(0, 5)
start_time =  datetime.now().time()
start = datetime.combine(date(1, 2, 3), start_time)  # here start is a datetime object
time1 = datetime.combine(date.min, start_time) - datetime.combine(date.min, timeobj)
tx = start+time1
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't make it complicated and you only need to compare start and timeobj(5AM).  Why? It is because you are simply comparing if current time is less than 5AM. Let's do some basic algebra.

```
given:
time1 = start - timeobj
tx = start + time1

thus: if (start >= tx) is the same with
      start >= start + start - timeobj
      0 >= start - timeobj
      timeobj >= start 
  (is current time earlier than 5am?)
```

UPDATED SCRIPT:

```
from datetime import datetime, date,time
timeobj = time(0, 5)
start = datetime.now().time()
#time1 = datetime.combine(date.min, start) - datetime.combine(date.min, timeobj)
#tx = start+time1 # throws error in here
if (timeobj >= start ):
    print('pass')
    pass #do stuff
```